# Python: retrieve attribute of <ObjectIdentifier>

Tags: python, cryptography

I am using cryptography to load a new certificate and retrieve its attributes.

```
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
path = "mycert.crt"
with open(path, 'rb') as cert_file:
    data = cert_file.read()
cert = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(data, default_backend())
sign = cert.signature_algorithm_oid
iss = cert.issuer
```

The last two print the result as:

```
print sign
<ObjectIdentifier(oid=1.1.1.1.1.1.11, name=sha256WithRSAEncryption)>

print iss
<Name([<NameAttribute(oid=<ObjectIdentifier(oid=1.1.1.1, name=countryName)>, value=u'GR')>, <NameAttribute(oid=<ObjectIdentifier(oid=1.1.1.1, name=organizationName)>, value=u'MyTrust')>, <NameAttribute(oid=<ObjectIdentifier(oid=2.5.4.3, name=commonName)>, value=u'MyTrust')>])>
```

How can I properly access one of those attributes?
For example, I want to print only the `sha256WithRSAEncryption` and only the `C=GR, O=MyTrust, CN=MyTrust`

After Danielle's response, I am updating the question.

```
>>> dir(iss)   
>>> ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__len__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_attributes', 'get_attributes_for_oid', 'public_bytes', 'rdns']
```

And when I print one it is still difficult to access:

```
>>> print(iss.__dict__)  
>>> {'_attributes': [<RelativeDistinguishedName([<NameAttribute(oid=<ObjectIdentifier(oid=2.5.4.6, name=countryName)>, value=u'GR')>])>, <RelativeDistinguishedName([<NameAttribute(oid=<ObjectIdentifier(oid=2.5.4.10, name=organizationName)>, value=u'MyTrust')>])>, <RelativeDistinguishedName([<NameAttribute(oid=<ObjectIdentifier(oid=2.5.4.11, name=organizationalUnitName)>, value=u'MyTrust')>])>, <RelativeDistinguishedName([<NameAttribute(oid=<ObjectIdentifier(oid=2.5.4.3, name=commonName)>, value=u'MyTrust')>])>]}
```

How can I get all the values?
countryName
organizationName
organizationalUnitName
commonName
etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to inspect an object and find it's attributes, try the `dir()` function:

```
>>> dir(sign)
>>> ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_dotted_string', '_name', 'dotted_string']
```

Maybe `_name` ?

```
>>> print(sign._name)
>>> sha1WithRSAEncryption
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir

Comment: Yes!!! The first one with `sign._name` worked perfect! However the second one is the problem. I will update the question above... This `dir` function is what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of the question, I am writing here the answer.

```
>>> cert.issuer
>>> for attribute in cert.issuer:
... print(attribute.oid._name)
... print(attribute.value)

countryName
GR
stateOrProvinceName
Blah
localityName
Blah
organizationName
MyTrust
organizationalUnitName
MyTrust
commonName
MyTrust
```

Thanks to Danielle that gave me insight about the function: dir()!!!